# Can a Component.gameObject be null in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject

Can a `Component.gameObject` be null in Unity? If it can what can cause it to be null?

The context for the question is a `NullReferenceException` I got from the users, which specifies only method, but not line in which it occurred.

So, I suspect that there may were conditions which cause `Component.gameObject` to be null.

Comment: It could also be a parameter with which you instantiate an object. Did you debug through and find out which line was throwing that error?

Comment: @Slagmoth, yes, I undertake all the measures I could in the development process, but I am still not able to pin a place which throwed the exception.

Comment: This would be easier to diagnose if you could provide a sample of the method code that's causing problems, and the context in which it's called.

Comment: Not sure if you are familiar with the term but you could "Carpet Bomb" to find the error. Sometimes debugging doesn't work with closed dlls and such, but you can log what goes in and where you expect it to change at each stage. It is tedious but has gleaned results in my production code on occasion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. Component.gameObject refers to the gameObject that the component (most likely your script) is from.

Therefore if you are referencing the 'gameObject' that the script is attached to it cannot be null (as the gameObject would have to exist for the script to exist and be running).

However, if you are referencing a component from a different GameObject and then using  Component.gameObject to find its gameObject, but the gameObject has been deleted/removed before this, the Coponent.gameObject will be null. To test this, you could try to reference the component itself. If the gameObject is null, the component itself should be null too (as it cannot exist without its gameObject.

(EDIT: As pointed out in the comments I made a mistake here. This would in fact throw a null reference exception, or one of Unity's errors. This is because, although the value is practically null, there is no 'null' value assigned to the gameObject reference, as the gameObject doesn't exist anymore. So, as you are trying to reference something that doesn't exist, it will actually be an error.  Sorry for not thinking this through. This means that this second scenario is actually impossible).

Most likely you are in the first scenario (where it cannot be null) and another factor is causing the exception. But without a more detailed description of the situation, this is the best I can do.

Comment: Eeh...your third paragraph isn't...quite true. If a GO has been destroyed, then its components have *also* been destroyed and `someComponent.gameObject` will throw a null reference exception *or* Unity's "an object has been destroyed but a script is still trying to reference it" error for objects that have had Destroy called on them but which haven't been GC'd yet (so are technically not null, but which are equal to null).